# Create folder inside storage based on user id in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, upload, laravel-5.1

I am trying to create folder inside storage folder based on user id. For example- if user with an id 1 is logged in, it should create a '1' folder inside storage folder and save uploaded file in that. It is creating the folder but not saving the uploaded file inside that '1' folder. I tried to change permission to 777 and 644 of storage folder after clearing application cache but it didnt work. Any Suggestions where am i going wrong.

Comment: What is the error message you receiving?? Include some code to make the question clear

Comment: Here is the code for make dir : Storage::makeDirectory($userid, 0777, $recursive = true); This is the error I  am getting  ErrorException in Local.php line 120:
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\deshbadlo\product\storage\app\avatars\1): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: are you using linux,mac or other os?? i am guessing your problem is not from coding.. You need to go to that directory via terminal and use chmod to give permission because framework is not getting write permission properly.. set recursive write permission to the parent folder where you are creating the folder

Comment: I am using windows with cygwin installed for cmd prompt. I already changed the storage folder permission to 777 and 644 recursively but no luck. When I used the same code to create dir inside public folder, it worked. I have no idea why its not creating folders inside storage/app/ even though I am giving folders the correct write permission. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to write something in folder which is protected by the framework so i suggest you that not to use those protected folder. use any other public folder to save images or files etc